# wpf checkbox binding inside listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, entity-framework-6

I have 2 classes generated by Entity Framework as follows. My requirement is depending on the SystemEntity_ID in the JobEntity class, I want to bind the IsChecked property of the checkbox in the listview. The problem is right now all the checkboxes are being checked...Please help..

```
public partial class JobEntity
{
    public int JobEntity_ID { get; set; }
    public int Job_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SystemEntity_ID { get; set; }
    public string EntityMigrationStatus { get; set; }
}

public partial class sp_SelectEntities_Result
{
    public Nullable<int> Project_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Site_ID { get; set; }
    public int SystemEntity_ID { get; set; }
    public string EntityDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Viewmodel class:

```
public class EntityViewModel
{
    private List<sp_SelectEntities_Result> entitylist;
    private ObservableCollection<sp_SelectEntities_Result> _ObCollection;
    private EntityDbContext db;
    List<int> Selectedvalues = new List<int>();
    public EntityViewModel()
    {
        db = new EntityDbContext();
        entitylist = db.sp_SelectEntities().ToList();
        convert();
    }

    public void convert()
    {
        _ObCollection = new ObservableCollection<sp_SelectEntities_Result>(entitylist);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<sp_SelectEntities_Result> obcollection
    {
        get { return _ObCollection; }
        set { _ObCollection = value; }
    }

}
```

My view i.e. MainWindow.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstentities" ItemsSource="{Binding obcollection}" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Selected">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="chk" IsChecked="{Binding SystemEntity_ID}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EntityDesc}" Header="Entity" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and in the mainwindow.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    EntityViewModel ev = new EntityViewModel();
    this.DataContext = ev;
}
```

Comment: you want to bing a int to a property that is a boolean? Is that correct?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to trigger a checked box? You're binding it to an integer, I would assume that the box would be checked as long as the integer is nonzero. If you want to make the box checked based on certain values, you need to use a value converter.

Comment: Actually lets say the in the database we have 2,3,4 then I want 2,3, and 4 checkboxes to be checked and along the same line if any checked changes lets say the user has unchecked 2, then I want to save 3,4 to the database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to bind nullable int to a boolean property.
If you want this any way. You need a converter or Data Trigger.

Since I don't know what value will make the checkbox checked and what value will make the checkbox unchecked, i can write any code for your.

Hope this helps.

Kind Regards

Comment: As earlier if I have 2,4 in the database then check boxes 2 and 4 needs to be checked and if any changes happens in the view, I need to store those values back to the database..Please help..if I need a value converter could you please help me with the code..I am so new to WPF..